# ADSI GetInfoEx not retrieving mail attribute

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, adsi

I can't get the Win32 ADSI c++ GetInfoEx API to retrieve the an AD user's mail attribute.
The Get call instead returns hr **0x8000500D** (E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND).
Any ideas of how I can get the get the mail attribute?  Here's my code.

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (hr == S_OK || hr == S_FALSE)
{
    IADs *pUsr = NULL;
    hr = ADsGetObject(L"WinNT://adomainname/ausername,user", IID_IADs, (void**)&pUsr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        VARIANT var;
        VariantInit(&var);

        LPWSTR pszAttrs[] = { L"mail" };
        DWORD dwNumber = sizeof(pszAttrs) / sizeof(LPWSTR);
        HRESULT hrAry = ADsBuildVarArrayStr(pszAttrs, dwNumber, &var);
        hr = pUsr->GetInfoEx(var, 0);
        VariantClear(&var);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hrAry) && SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pUsr->Get(CComBSTR("mail"), &var);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                printf("mail: %S\n", V_BSTR(&var));
                VariantClear(&var);
            }
        }
        if (pUsr)
            pUsr->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mail` attribute is not available when using the WinNT provider: [Unsupported IADsUser Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/unsupported-iadsuser-properties)

You have to use LDAP.

If you have the `distinguishedName` of the account, you can use that:

```
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://CN=someuser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com", IID_IADs, (void**)&pUsr);
```

If all you have is the domain and username, then you can use `LDAP://adomainname` and search domain for the username with the filter:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=ausername))
```

Or you can use [`IADsNameTranslate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsnametranslate) to translate the domain\username (`ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4`) into the distinguished name (`ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779`).